# Keep simpleserver active even on syntax errors

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

Is there a way to configure the simple-server that Flask uses to **not** exit on every single syntax error?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_debugger=True, passthrough_errors=False);
```

Currently I'm using this setup for the simple-server.
Setting passthrough_errors to False means most of the errors actually keeps the process alive so that I can use the interactive debugger, syntax errors still exits the program though. I've tried different configuration values but I have not found anything that works. Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/549

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Python documentation there are two types or errors:

1. Syntax Errors
2. Exceptions

Syntax errors are produced during **parse time** (at that moment your code **doesn't** actually executes, so you have no possibility to catch errors, since parse time is not a runtime, when your code actually executes).

The only way you can catch syntax errors is when they happen inside a piece of code given as an argument to *exec* function (executes string of python code):

```
>>> try:
...     exec('x===6')
... except SyntaxError:
...     print('Hello!')
...
Hello!
```

But you must remember to use exec() only when you really know what you do. It's not recommended to use exec() at all especially when it depends on user input.

Comment: Is there really no way to keep the server alive then? It seems like a really annoying problem to keep restarting the server.

Comment: In Python syntax errors are just another exception type. You can catch them when calling exec(), but you can also catch them on imports too. Just wrap your import in try/except and you can catch the SyntaxError there as well.

Answer (score 5):

I just posted a [Flask-Failsafe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Failsafe/) extension to solve this exact issue.

I hit this all the time and ran across your post earlier looking for a solution. After a bit of experimenting I hacked up a decorator you can use to wrap your initialization code so that if it fails the reloader will keep working. Check it out and let me know what you think.